# This is my code for the CS50 Readability assignment. Why is the global variable in my function not updating? It always gives 0 words

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50, c-strings, function-definition

Is the problem checking it using ASCII code because this is what we learnt in CS50. I'm trying to check for spaces and the ASCII code for a space is 32.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_words(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int no_of_words = count_words(text);
    printf("no_of_words %i \n", no_of_words);
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int i;
    int words_counter = 0;
    int n = strlen(text);
    
    
    for (i = 0; i > n; i++)
    {
        char test = text[i];
        if (test == 32)
        {
            words_counter++;
        }
    }
    return words_counter;
}
```

Comment: i dont see a global variable.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `32` for space. Use `' '` for space.

Comment: Your condition is wrong: `for (i = 0; i > n; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Note: counting the spaces is a crude and inexact way of counting words. For example `"three little words"` has only 2 spaces, `"two    words"` has 3 spaces, and `"two,words"` has none.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop within the function has an invalid condition

```
for (i = 0; i > n; i++)
            ^^^^^^
```

It seems you mean

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
             ^^^^^^
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 32

```
if (test == 32)
```

It would be more readable to write

```
if ( test == ' ' )
```

But in any case the approach used in the function is incorrect because the user can enter for example a string consisting of all spaces. In this case the function will return an invalid counter of words.

The function can be written the following way

```
size_t count_words( string text )
{
    size_t words_counter = 0;
    
    while ( *text )
    {
        while ( *text == ' ' ) ++text;
        
        if ( *text ) ++words_counter;

        while ( *text && *text != ' ' ) ++text;
    } 

    return words_counter;
}
```

And in main it is called like

```
size_t no_of_words = count_words(text);
printf("no_of_words %zu \n", no_of_words);
```

If to take also in account tab characters then the function can look the following way

```
size_t count_words( string text )
{
    size_t words_counter = 0;
    
    while ( *text )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*text ) ) ++text;
        
        if ( *text ) ++words_counter;

        while ( *text && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*text ) ) ++text;
    } 

    return words_counter;
}
```